# How to use sqoop to import data from database to multiple hdfs file?

Tags: sqoop

I am using sqoop to import data from oracle to hdfs in avro format. I want to parallel this process by writing to multiple hdfs file (one per mapper instance) because the record orders is not important for me. Is there an option to do that in sqoop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--as-avrodatafile` to specify the file format and use `-m 4` to specify the number of mappers.

[Documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax).